# Why do fonts get pixelated at lower font-sizes?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, font-size, google-font-api, cleartype

I'm trying to understand how I can keep my fonts looking as nice as they do at a `font-size` of 64px when using something such as 36px.  I'm currently using Google Fonts' `Open Sans`.  The font looks nice at 64px (or even 49px), but not nice at 36px.  Below is the css and screenshots of each.

**CSS**

```
    .h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 1.1em;

        font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

**36px**

[image]

**64px**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

less size means only a couple of pixels are available for font rendering. more the no. of pixels, more the clarity. take the example of an ellipse. the more no. of points u use to draw the ellipse, more accurate the ellipse will be.

about ur anti-aliasing issue - sorry, there's nothing u can do on chrome/opera on windows. ie antialiases fonts. but not chrome/opera. in mac thought fonts get antialiased even at small sizes.

update[1]

try the premium font 'Helvetica Neue'. It looks the same with/without antialiasing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there perhaps a way to search for other fonts that might operate similarly to `Helvetica Neue`?